# Can't remeber my Alias password how can i find it?

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play

**Hey I want to update my application in google play, 
and i forgot my Alias password .
what can i do to recover my password?**

Comment: You have a big problem. No recovery is possible.

Comment: you only forgot the password, or you lost the whole keystore file?

Comment: @MirecXP oh come, on it is possible ... brute force method allways works :)... since password lenght is finite it should even take finite time to find password out ...

Comment: @Selvin - possible ? - yes, practical? -no.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can't! You have to create a new keystore. But! Google Play Store won't allow you to use new keystore with an already uploaded application. You have to delete your app from the store and upload it again with new keystore. But this will cause you to start from zero download number. So try to contact Google Play Store to find a way. Probably they will help you.